# Proving the ideal $I=\{f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x] | f(0)$ is even$\}$ is not principal in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I want to prove that the Ideal $I=\{f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x] | f(0)$ is even$\}$ is not principal in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. I have proved that, in fact $I=(2,x)$

Now, I think that should be enough (why not?), since the ideal I is now generated by 2 elements. However my professor followed saying:

To see that $I$ is not principal, we suppose that $I=(f(x))$ and we get to a contradiction. How do I get to that contradiction?

Comment: Is there a polynomial which divides both $x$ and $2$ in $\Bbb Z[X]$?

Comment: "Why not": Saying an ideal _is_ generated by two elements does not imply _a priori_ that it is _not_ generated by one element.